# Add prefix to specific columns of Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I've a DataFrame like that :

```
col1   col2   col3   col4   col5   col6   col7   col8
0      5345   rrf    rrf    rrf    rrf    rrf    rrf
1      2527   erfr   erfr   erfr   erfr   erfr   erfr
2      2727   f      f      f      f      f      f
```

I would like to rename all columns but not **col1** and **col2**.

So I tried to make a loop

```
print(df.columns)
    for col in df.columns:
        if col != 'col1' and col != 'col2':
            col.rename = str(col) + '_x'
```

But it's not very efficient...it doesn't work !

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use the [DataFrame.rename()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) method

```
new_names = [(i,i+'_x') for i in df.iloc[:, 2:].columns.values]
df.rename(columns = dict(new_names), inplace=True)
```

Comment: Great solution! Additional comment: `new_names = [(i,i+'_x') for i in df.columns if i not in ['col1','col2']]`

Answer (score 11):

Simpliest solution if `col1` and `col2` are first and second column names:

```
df.columns = df.columns[:2].union(df.columns[2:]  + '_x')
print (df)
   col1  col2 col3_x col4_x col5_x col6_x col7_x col8_x
0     0  5345    rrf    rrf    rrf    rrf    rrf    rrf
1     1  2527   erfr   erfr   erfr   erfr   erfr   erfr
2     2  2727      f      f      f      f      f      f
```

Another solution with [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) or list comprehension:

```
cols = df.columns[~df.columns.isin(['col1','col2'])]
print (cols)
['col3', 'col4', 'col5', 'col6', 'col7', 'col8']

df.rename(columns = dict(zip(cols, cols + '_x')), inplace=True)

print (df)

   col1  col2 col3_x col4_x col5_x col6_x col7_x col8_x
0     0  5345    rrf    rrf    rrf    rrf    rrf    rrf
1     1  2527   erfr   erfr   erfr   erfr   erfr   erfr
2     2  2727      f      f      f      f      f      f
```

---

```
cols = [col for col in df.columns if col not in ['col1', 'col2']]
print (cols)
['col3', 'col4', 'col5', 'col6', 'col7', 'col8']

df.rename(columns = dict(zip(cols, cols + '_x')), inplace=True)

print (df)

   col1  col2 col3_x col4_x col5_x col6_x col7_x col8_x
0     0  5345    rrf    rrf    rrf    rrf    rrf    rrf
1     1  2527   erfr   erfr   erfr   erfr   erfr   erfr
2     2  2727      f      f      f      f      f      f
```

The fastest is list comprehension:

```
df.columns = [col+'_x' if col != 'col1' and col != 'col2' else col for col in df.columns]
```

**Timings**:

```
In [350]: %timeit (akot(df))
1000 loops, best of 3: 387 µs per loop

In [351]: %timeit (jez(df1))
The slowest run took 4.12 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
10000 loops, best of 3: 207 µs per loop

In [363]: %timeit (jez3(df2))
The slowest run took 6.41 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
10000 loops, best of 3: 75.7 µs per loop
```

---

```
df1 = df.copy()
df2 = df.copy()

def jez(df):
    df.columns = df.columns[:2].union(df.columns[2:]  + '_x')
    return df

def akot(df):
    new_names = [(i,i+'_x') for i in df.iloc[:, 2:].columns.values]
    df.rename(columns = dict(new_names), inplace=True)
    return df


def jez3(df):
   df.columns = [col + '_x' if col != 'col1' and col != 'col2' else col for col in df.columns]
   return df


print (akot(df))
print (jez(df1))
print (jez2(df1))
```

Comment: I add timings, please check it.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) with a regex pattern to filter the cols of interest, then using `zip` construct a dict and pass this as the arg to [`rename`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html):

```
In [94]:
cols = df.columns[~df.columns.str.contains('col1|col2')]
df.rename(columns = dict(zip(cols, cols + '_x')), inplace=True)
df

Out[94]:
   col1  col2 col3_x col4_x col5_x col6_x col7_x col8_x
0     0  5345    rrf    rrf    rrf    rrf    rrf    rrf
1     1  2527   erfr   erfr   erfr   erfr   erfr   erfr
2     2  2727      f      f      f      f      f      f
```

So here using `str.contains` to filter the columns will return the columns that don't match so the column order is irrelevant

Comment: Wahou ! It's perfect ! It is possible to use `str.value =` or a code like that ?

Comment: Not sure what you're attempting with that code snippet, but generally you need to use `rename` or overwrite the columns attribute directly

Answer (score 1):

### Quick solution that works for me

As [EdChum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/704848/edchum) suggested, I used `str.contains` and ~ to filter out the columns

```
cols = df.columns[~df.columns.str.contains('col1|col2')]
```

then used rename function of pandas

```
df.rename(columns={col: col + '_x' for col in df.columns if col in cols}, inplace=True)
```

---

P.S. `df.rename(columns = dict(zip(cols, cols + '_x')), inplace=True)` did not work in my case.